# Bootstrap dialog window opens behind another dialog window instead of infront

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

A dialog window is incorrectly opening behind another dialog window. I use  the #modalMidWestEquipPlans data target to open the dialog window. How do I tweak the code so that the  hyperlink opens the dialog window in front? Most solutions to a similar issue talk about tweaking a z-index but I do not have that in this code.
Thank you

```
            <div class="col col mb-4">
            <div class="card metro-card rounded mb-0 bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#modalEquipPlans">
                            Equipment
                        </button>
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEquipPlans" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalEquipPlansTitle"
aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title ModalTitleOR" id="modalEquipPlansLongTitle">Equipment</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <strong>Equipment Plans</strong>
            <div class="list-group">

                <!-- (other list group items removed) -->

                <div class="list-group-item bg-danger h5 fake-btn">
                    <a class="clsPointer"  data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modalMidWestEquipPlans">
                  <span class="addUnderlines">AFTER CLICKING THIS HYPERLINK, THE DIALOG BOX OPENS BEHIND THIS DIALOG INSTEAD OF IN FRONT</span> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the source code as text.

Comment: We don't debug images. Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: text code added